# AdminLTE expanded sidebar submenu collapses in Flask

Tags: html, flask, adminlte

I'm a beginner in web development. I'm trying to use the `AdminLTE` in my flask application. I basically copied the contents of adminLTE into a folder,`static` and then referenced all the adminLTE stylesheets and javascripts by changing the the hrefs, for example: from `href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css"` to `href="static/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css"`

```
flask_app/
    app.py
    static/
        bower_components/
        css/
        dist/
        fonts/
        js/
        plugins/
    templates/
        mypage1.html
        mypage2.html
```

This works for my pages `mypage1.html` and `mypage2.html`, but the issue I have is with the sidebar menu and submenus. Assuming `mypage2.html` is a submenu, when I expand and click on its link from `mypage1.html`, it reloads the entire page thereby collapsing the submenu. How can I persist the state such that submenu stays expanded when `mypage2.html` loads.

Here's a snippet from the sidebar:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
<li class="header">HEADER</li>
<li class="active">
   <a href="{{ url_for('mypage1') }}">
   <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>MyPage1</span>
   </a>
</li>
<li class="treeview">
   <a href="#">
   <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
   <span>Submenu</span>
   <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
   </a>
   <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li>
         <a href="{{ url_for('mypage2') }}">
         <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
         MyPage2
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add css class name: **menu-open** in ul treeview-menu, and also move ccs class name **active** to desire active li element, like this:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
<li class="header">HEADER</li>
<li>
   <a href="{{ url_for('mypage1') }}">
   <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>MyPage1</span>
   </a>
</li>
<li class="treeview">
   <a href="#">
   <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
   <span>Submenu</span>
   <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
   </a>
   <ul class="treeview-menu menu-open">
      <li class="active">
         <a href="{{ url_for('mypage2') }}">
         <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
         MyPage2
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```